# Fastest way to compute only last row in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find the fastest way to compute the results only for the last row in a dataframe. For some reason, when I do so it is slower than computing the entire dataframe. What am I doing wrong here? What would be the correct way to access only the last two rows and compute their values?

Currently these are my results:

Processing time of add_complete(): 1.333 seconds
Processing time of add_last_row_only(): 1.502 seconds

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def add_complete(df):
    df['change_a'] = df['a'].diff()
    df['change_b'] = df['b'].diff()
    df['factor'] = df['change_a'] * df['change_b']

def add_last_row_only(df):
    df.at[df.index[-1], 'change_a_last_row'] = df['a'].iloc[-1] - df['a'].iloc[-2]
    df.at[df.index[-1], 'change_b_last_row'] = df['b'].iloc[-1] - df['b'].iloc[-2]
    df.at[df.index[-1], 'factor_last_row'] = df['change_a_last_row'].iloc[-1] * df['change_b_last_row'].iloc[-1]

def main():
    a = np.arange(200_000_000).reshape(100_000_000, 2)
    df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a', 'b'])
    add_complete(df)
    add_last_row_only(df)
    print(df.tail())
```

Comment: I assume this is because pandas (and underlying numpy) uses vectorised c functions to do the computations in add_complete(). Therefore, there is no (large) difference in computation time for performing the operation on a scalar vs on a vector. A assume the computation time of the actual mathematical operations in add_last_row_only() are almost the same as those in add_complete() but it does add extra time for all the selections that are done. I didn't verify this with tests but it's my best guess

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something, for this kind of operation I would use numpy on the two last lines:

```
%%timeit
changes = np.diff(df.values[-2:,:],axis=0)
factor = np.product(changes)
```

**21µs** just this operation, yes, microseconds.

If I add insertion it increases to **511ms**, even filling all with same value.
I suspect the problem comes from handling around a 1.5Gb dataframe, which actually doubles the size when inserting the two extra columns.

```
%%timeit
changes = np.diff(df.values[-2:,:],axis=0)
factor = np.product(changes)
df['factor']=factor
df['changes_a']=changes[0][0]
df['changes_b']=changes[0][1]
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, it definitely cuts some time, I've tried a few different insertion methods, but can't seem to find anything that is faster. Would a db like mysql potentially be faster?

Comment: The overhead comes from creating the missing columns. If you only need some entries, creating entries for all rows is overkill. I am not familiar with pandas support for sparse matrices, but adding "full columns" is definitely not the answer